# Google play store is giving extra credits to user?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play-services

We are using server side validation for validating in-app subscription in play store. Google returned such a response for one of the requests -

`{
kind: "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase",

initiationTimestampMsec: "1363062617125",

validUntilTimestampMsec: "1365762617125",

autoRenewing: true

}`

Its a monthly subscription and if you convert the timestamps, validUntilTimestampMsec is 6 hours more than a month, any idea why?

Comment: Why is this closed as off topic? I have the same problem but with a delay of 12 hours. @Shrinath, do you have found a solution for your problem? Here is my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919332/invalid-expire-date-after-subscription-purchase

Comment: @MartinVonMartinsgrün, didn't get a reply from anyone nor from google.  I coded around it such that we always calculate our own validuntil.